# Apply function to the second level if the first level is integral from zero to infinity, otherwise, not evaluate

Tags: function-construction, pattern-matching

How can I make a function, say, `R[expression]` such that it works on arguments like this `Integrate[f[x],{x,0,Infinity}]`, applying some operator `r[]` to the function under integral, and leaving the epression unevaluated if the first level is not an integral from zero to infinity?

For instance, `R[Integrate[Sin[x],x]]` should produce `Integrate[r[Sin[x]],x]]` but `R[Sin[x]]` should be left unevaluated.

I have tried to match the pattern this way but it did not work:

`R[Integrate[f_[x_], {x_, 0, Infinity}]] := Integrate[r[f[x]], {x, 0, Infinity}]`

Comment: Your function `R` needs to hold its arguments, otherwise the argument will be evaluated before `R` can do anything. So use `SetAttributes[R, HoldFirst]`, for example.

Answer (score 5):

To elaborate on my comment:

```
ClearAll[R]
SetAttributes[R, HoldFirst]
R[Integrate[f_[x_], {x_, 0, Infinity}]] := Integrate[r[f[x]], {x, 0, Infinity}]

R[Integrate[Sin[x], {x, 0, Infinity}]]
R[Integrate[Sin[x], {x, 0, 1}]]
R[Integrate[Sin[x], x]]
R[Sin[x]]
```

You specified that the expression should remain unevaluated if it's not an integral from 0 to `Infinity`, so I assume the 2nd and 3rd lines should not evaluate.

Comment: Thanks! This works well!

Comment: Hmm, it does not work if under the integral a simple expression of `x`...

Answer (score 2):

Not at my computer but the following should give slightly more general solution.

```
ClearAll[rInt]
SetAttributes[rInt, HoldFirst]
rInt[Integrate[f_, x:{_Symbol,0,Infinity}..]] :=Integrate[r[f], x]
```

Then the following give the expected result

```
rInt[Sin[x]]

rInt[Integrate[Sin[u],u]]

rInt[Integrate[Sin[y],{y,0,Infinity}]]

rInt[Integrate[u^2 - Log[v],{u,0,Infinity},{v,0,Infinity}]]
```

Hope this helps.